# Which Hardware Runs OpenCL on Intel Core Processors?

Tags: opencl, intel, hardware-acceleration

I'm thinking about opportunities for parallelism  by combining OpenCL and AVX on Intel i7 platforms, but I don't think this is a possibility. Although, I understand that the CPU and iGPU share the same memory bandwidth, I'm not certain if they share any other hardware?

Does open OpenCL run on the iGPU ("Intel Graphics Processor") or the AVX units ("CPU cores")?

[image]

Comment: if you query for GPU devices, iGPU is returned. If you query CPU types, CPU is returned, you can use both concurrently. My C3060 works well enough. 12 execution units of igpu > 1 core of cpu for streaming( and much better for computing). Intel compiler is good enough to produce SSE for this cpu. But for i7, AVX is very probable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCL can be run on CPUs and GPUs. If you set the target device as the Intel CPU and the openCL is compiled using Intel compiler, then it is highly probable that the compiled code can exploit the SSE/AVX units. And you can also write your own vectorized code in the openCL kernel to exploit the AVX units.